# Can't style certain div with css

Tags: html, css

I'm styling this page and yet I can't seem to access either .4thForm or .3rdForm to style. These elements move responsively when screensize drops below 1024px so it's cruitial that I access these elements.

I've tested the @media call and I can change the colour .frontbannertitle with it so I know it's not the media call. Using inspector I can code the element to achieve what I would like, but it will not let me generate a css element to style it.

I need to edit this div to provide it with a negative margin-top value, as that cannot be achieved by targeting the select within the div.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P49ja/

```
<form class="frontbannercontainer form-horizontal">
    <fieldset class="frontbanner">
        <h1 class="frontbannertitle">Enquire Now!</h1>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="textinput1" class="frontbannertext input-xlarge" type="text" name="textinput">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="textinput2" class="frontbannertext input-xlarge" type="text" name="textinput">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls 3rdForm">
                <input id="textinput3" class="frontbannertext input-xlarge" type="text" name="textinput">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls 4thForm">
                <select id="selectbasic" class="frontbannerselect input-xlarge" name="selectbasic">
                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="0">Select Membership</option>
                    <option value="1">Individual Membership</option>
                    <option value="2">Corporate Membership</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="SliderFormPhone">
            <span id="ques">Enquire By Phone:</span>
            <span id="ph">(02) 000 000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button id="singlebutton" class="frontbannerbutton btn btn-primary" name="singlebutton">Apply!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share you CSS code, that are related to those divs..

Comment: can you show us your css? & it would be great if you can create a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: You have `ID`s overriding your `classes`. Just saying it's likely, based on the fact I can't see your `css`. But even then, there are better ways to accomplish this. Toss a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) out here....?

Comment: Just threw a jsfiddle up. the surrounding CSS doesn't do much at the moment in terms of pageflow, so shouldn't affect calling an element I don't think.

Comment: Check the class naming conventions plz. First letter must be character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P49ja/3/)**

You can not start a class with a number in your case it's `.4thForm`

Change it to something like `.Form4th`

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot use "3rdForm" as a valid class selector.
The first character cannot be numeric.

Refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors).

I added "thirdForm" as a class to your fiddle and was able to style it properly. So I'm assuming that is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add special character "\3" to access this class like below..

```
.\34thform{
display:none;    
margin-top:-7em;
  }
```

sample jsfiddle below...
http://jsfiddle.net/P49ja/4/